# Skip one element of enhanced for loop

Tags: java, foreach

While working with graphs I have found frequently I need to skip one element while looping. Is there a way do to this with out calling an if statement in each cycle of the loop?

example:

```
private void printAll(Node<T> root){
        System.err.println(toString());
        for(Node<T> node : links.values()){
            if (node == root) continue;
            node.printAll(this);
        }
}
```

I suspect the answer is no, but would like to confirm.

EDIT: The question is, is there a way to iterate a data structure skipping one known element without using an if statement with an enhanced for loop or some other method.

Comment: why would you need to confirm this....just try it out.

Comment: if (node.equals(root)) would work as long as you properly implemented equals() I guess?

Comment: @Don how can I try this out? How do I try out the idea that there is no other way to do this without using an if statement to skip one element?

Comment: @Wonhee yes but you are still using an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [enhanced for loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) do:

> Its simple structure allows one to simplify code by presenting for-loops that visit **each** element of an array/collection without explicitly expressing how one goes from element to element.

The keyword there is `each`. That means `each and every`, not `all but one`. If you want `all but one` (or some other variant like `all but those meeting some criteria`, you need to code for that with a conditional.

Or, $DEITY forbid, construct a *new* collection containing only what you want to process then `foreach` that. That's probably an even worse idea since it will still have to use a conditional to construct the new collection so you're really gaining nothing.

Maybe it would be *nice* to have a syntax like:

```
for (Node<T> node :in links.values() :where node != root)
    node.printAll(this);
```

(I believe LINQ provides this for the Microsoft stable) but that would just be syntactic sugar for what you already have. The *code* may be shorter but you'd still be doing the same sort of work under the covers.

Comment: I understand clearly how enhanced for loops work. Thus you did not address the real question at all.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs, if you read closely, I think that's covered by the `keyword: each` section. It's a hammer-to-the-head way of saying "no, it's not possible" (granted, Don could have possibly made it clearer). Each means each, not all-but-one. If you want all-but-one, you need to code for that or, $DEITY forbid, construct a new collection containing only what you want to process then `foreach` that.

Comment: @Paxdiablo thank you, this is basically what I thought but wanted to confirm. I've had to repeat this pattern a number of times and wanted to make sure there was no better way to do it. If you submit your comment as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Michael, I may just modify this one since mine would only really be a bit of extra explanation and it's not like I need the rep :-)